# How can I add space between buttons?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to add space between buttons and I have looked for the ways but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

```
for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
  var newbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("  "+res[i]);
  newbutton.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(newbutton);
}
```

I want to put space between the buttons from the end result. 
I think I have to use setattribute but don't know how and where.
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You should be using CSS for this.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS for something like this.  Adding a right margin will do what you've asked...

```js
var res = ["button1", "button2", "button3", "button4"];

for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
    var newbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("  "+res[i]);
    newbutton.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(newbutton);
}
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin for that:

```
for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
  var newbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("  "+res[i]);
  newbutton.appendChild(t);
  newbutton.style.marginRight = "5px";
  document.body.appendChild(newbutton);
}
```